# JavaScript split add an extra empty array item?

Tags: javascript

The following code reads a file and turned each line into array items:

```
fs.readFile('en.txt', 'utf8', function (err, data) {
  if (err) {
    return console.log(err)
  }

  enStrings = data.split(/[\r\n]+/g)
}
```

`en.txt` looks like this:

```
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
```

But I'm puzzled. `console.log(enStrings)` outputs this:

```
[ 'Line 1', 'Line 2', 'Line 3', '' ]
```

Why is that last empty item being added? And how to remove it?

Comment: Since you are splitting by the new line character it is understandable that there would be an empty line marking the end of the file. You may need to explicitly remove the empty line after reading the file.

Answer (score 7):

This would happen if your text file has a trailing new line character, which is common.

Why not `trim` before splitting?

```
enStrings = data.trim().split(/[\r\n]+/g);
```

Alternately, you could remove just the trailing new line characters before splitting.

```
enStrings = data.replace(/[\n\r]+$/, '').split(/[\r\n]+/g)
```

However, if your data is long, you may want to avoid the performance hit of recreating the entire string before splitting. If that is the case, you could use the following to pop it off the end.

```
if (enStrings.length && !enStrings[enStrings.length-1]) {
    enStrings.pop();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```
console.log(enStrings.filter(Boolean));
```

Empty strings are falsy value so using `.filter(Boolean)` will only list the truthy value and removes the empty strings from your array.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
enStrings = data.split(/[\r\n]+/g);
enStrings.splice($.inArray('', enStrings), 1);
```

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara I just edit my answer, you can check again